# How to make the like button turn blue on a mock HTML YouTube page?

Tags: html, css, youtube

I'm hosting a static mock YouTube page on Amazon AWS using HTML for research (see attached screenshot) and want to make the like button turn blue after clicking. Does anyone know how to make that happen? Thanks a bunch in advance!

Below is the code I used:

```
function like_clicked(){
        var val1 = 0;
        var val2 = 0;
    
        if(!liked){
            val1 = 1;
        }
        else{
            val1 = -1;
        }
        
        if(disliked){
            val2 = -1
            disliked = false;
        }
        liked = !liked;
        
        var params_new = {
            TableName: table,
            Key:{
            "PageName": pageName,
            },
            UpdateExpression: "set Likes = Likes + :val1, Dislikes = Dislikes + :val2",
            ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ":val1":val1,
            ":val2":val2
            },
            ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
        };
        docClient.update(params_new, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("Unable to update database. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            } else {
                console.log("Update like_Clicked succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                like.textContent = data.Attributes.Likes;
                dislike.textContent = data.Attributes.Dislikes;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hello Meemo Li and welcome! Do you mind sharing what you've tried to make this work? Can you post your JS code? What is the `like_clicked()' function doing? Thanks!

Comment: @Erik Thanks for your response and suggestion! I have updated the code in the question above.